# Android TV Play Video from URL

Tags: android-tv

I would like to play a MP4 video from a URL in my Android TV app.

I couldn't find an example in the Sample code (https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback).

Does anyone know how to do that?
Do I need to create my own Activity or is there a standard one in the leanback support library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The androidtv-Leanback example **already includes video playback**.

If you take a look at the [PlaybackOverlayActivity](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/tvleanback/ui/PlaybackOverlayActivity.java), you will see that the `VideoView` class is used to play sample videos (you can find the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html)).

However, there is no standard component in the Leanback support library, so you will have to define an Activity yourself.

Comment: Wow. That seems really complicated for just playing a video and some controls... Have you done any app with this kind of video playback?

Comment: I don't think it's that complicated (in terms of code quantity and complexity). Usually, video playback involves quite a lot of work. For the controls part, the `PlaybackOverlayFragment` widget does a great part of the heavy lifting for you (see here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/PlaybackOverlayFragment.html)

Comment: Yeah I was finally able to copy paste `PlaybackOverlayFragment` and `PlaybackOverlayActivity` and tweak it a little bit to make it work in my app. Thanks for the help.