# Playing videos in Android TV through sd card and also from URL

Tags: video, mp4, android-tv, playing

When i try to play MP4 file on Android TV using Video view, It's showing blank part in place of video view  but i am hearing audio. Can you send me the sample code which will play videos in Android TV. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Check the official google android tv sample using the [leanback library](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/tvleanback/ui/PlaybackOverlayActivity.java). You an also refer to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27891487/android-tv-play-video-from-url) for additional insight.